# JavaScript code does not working on my ASP.NET web form?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Did everything, searched everywhere, thought everytime but now
Tried my best but still can't handle it. Now running into a problem with a form submit to push data search to controller with javascript code.

I am not getting any error for the JavaScript when attempting to debug in browser. Can someone with more experience with JavaScript show me a better way with the given code?

*Here is my code:*

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult FindProduct(string keyword)
{
    List<Product> ls = new List<Product>();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword) || keyword.Length < 1)
    {
        return PartialView("ListProductSearchPartial", null);
    }
    ls = _context.Products
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(a => a.Cat)
        .Where(x => x.ProductName.Contains(keyword))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductName)
        .Take(10)
        .ToList();
    if (ls == null)
    {
        return PartialView("ListProductSearchPartial", null);
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("ListProductSearchPartial", ls);
    }
}
```

**Form Search in View index:**

```
<form id="formSearch" class="header-searchbox">
    <select class="nice-select select-search-category wide">
        <option value="all">All Category</option>
        <option value="product-item">Product Item</option>
        <option value="product-item-2">Product Item 02</option>
        <option value="product-item-3">Product Item 03</option>
        <option value="product-item-4">Product Item 04</option>
        <option value="product-item-5">Product Item 05</option>
    </select>
    <input id="keyword" class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Enter Products">
    <button id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-outline-whisper btn-primary-hover" type="submit"><i class="pe-7s-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

**Javascript in View index:**

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var formSP = document.getElementById("formSearch");
            formSP.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("FindProduct", "Search")',
                    datatype: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { keyword: $('#keyword').val() },
                    async: true,
                    success: function (results) {
                        $('#records_table').html("");
                        $('#records_table').html(results);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Update:** I have found the solution by myself, but now figuring out any way to pass a return list from controller to partialview...

Comment: you probably need to *prevent* the *default* action of the form submit *event* through a *listener*

Comment: @Jaromanda X you mean I need put more "e.preventDefault()" to the first line of the "addEventListener"?

Comment: I had tried this before made a question here, but sadly no, it didn't work :(

Comment: Everything is done, I solved this!